# Test Rake tasks in silent mode

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

My rake task looks like that

```
task :install do
  Module1.install
end
```

Module1 has multiple logical steps with bunch of "puts" statements which prints debug info.

How can I test this rake task(by testing `Module1.install` directly) so that it would not print all the debug info right into testing console?

Is there any more idiomatic way than patching puts method in Kernel module?

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign `$stdout` for this task:

```
require "stringio"

task :install do
  new_stdout = StringIO.new
  old_stdout = $stdout  
  $stdout = new_stdout

  Module1.install

  $stdout = old_stdout
end
```